# webpack - scss cannot resolve background-image url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, webpack-5, urlloader

In my scss file, I use `background-image: url("../../../assets/images/home/banner-mobile.png");`

The application runs successfully, but no background image is shown:

The background image URL is not resolved.
[image]

webpack/webpack.base.js

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");

const utils = require("./utils");

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.jsx",
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": utils.resolve("src")
    },
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"],
    fallback: {...},
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader",
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-resources-loader",
            options: {
              resources: ["./src/assets/scss/main.scss"],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "url-loader",
            options: {
              limit: 8192
            },
          },
        ],
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "public/index.html",
      filename: "index.html",
      inject: true,
    })
  ],
};
```

webpack/webpack.dev.js

```
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const base = require("./webpack.base");

const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");

module.exports = merge(base, {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    static: true,
    static: 'dist'
  },
  plugins: [new Dotenv({ path: "./.env.development" })],
});
```

**Update 1**

When I view the png in Web Inspector > Sources:
[image]

When I open the image with its URL in the browser:
[image]

**Update 2:**

When I build and view the image via VSCode, it shows below:
[image]

Not sure if the below file-is related

webpack/Util.js

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  resolve: function(dir) {
    return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the relative path is correct? It should be relative to the CSS file itself.

Comment: @Terry yes, it's correct.

Comment: I mean, it certainly looks like Webpack resolved _some_ image. It didn't come up with `1caaf59….png` from nothing. What do you see if you open that image URL directly?

Comment: @Phil If i open the png, it shows image with white background, not my image

Comment: But it's an actual, valid PNG image?

Comment: @Phil please check my above update

Comment: FYI, that little white square is the _"not an actual image"_ image. Can you try building your app (so it produces static files) and see exactly what that image is? Check it in a hex editor or similar

Comment: @Phil PLEASE check above

Comment: What version of Webpack are you using? Are you aware that the [url-loader](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/) is deprecated in v5?

Comment: @Phil Oh I am using webpack `5.64.2`, but I tried below commnent still not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using Webpack 5, I'd recommend using [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) instead of the deprecated loaders

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    // ...
    {
      test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
      type: "asset",
      parser: {
        dataUrlCondition: {
          maxSize: 8192
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I suspect you were running into a resource handling duplication issue as noted in the documentation...

> When using the old assets loaders (i.e. `file-loader` / `url-loader` / `raw-loader`) along with Asset Module in webpack 5, you might want to stop Asset Module from processing your assets again as that would result in asset duplication. This can be done by setting asset's module type to `'javascript/auto'`.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

After a long search, the only solution I found is to use `~` to reference the initial project directory and accessing public folder from there.

```
background-image: url("~/public/images/icon.png");
```

And this is working fine for me :)

**OR** And the other alternative would be to move images to the `src` directory, and this won't be a problem since webpack would pack them in a folder called `static/media` as static files

Answer (score 0):

I use file-loader as shown in this rule, it allow me to preserve the file name and relative path, so having my folder structure like assets > images, I just have to strip "assets" from the path:

```
{
  test: /\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/,
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: {
    name: '[path][name].[ext]',
    outputPath: (file) => {
      const p = file.split('assets/')[1];
      return p;
    },
  },
},
```

This will let you with all images within "assets" folder right into the root bundle and every path will be replicated (ex. assets/images/home/banner.png will be on images/home/banner.png in your dist directory), just be sure all your images are inside your assets folder to avoid getting name conflicts